# python discord.py send DM to inviter on join guild

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.py

I currently have the following `on_guild_join` code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Eric Bot', color=0xaa0000)
    embed.add_field(name="What's up everyone? I am **Eric Bot**.", value='\nTry typing `/help` to get started.', inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text='Thanks for adding Eric Bot to your server!')
    await guild.system_channel.send(embed=embed)
    print(f'{c.bgreen}>>> {c.bdarkred}[GUILD JOINED] {c.black}ID: {guild.id} Name: {guild.name}{c.bgreen} <<<\n{c.darkwhite}Total Guilds: {len(client.guilds)}{c.end}')
```

(Ignore the `c.color` stuff, it's my formatting on the console)

It sends an embed with a bit of information to the system channel whenever someone adds the bot to a guild.
I want it to send a DM to whoever invited the bot (the account that used the oauth authorize link) the same message. The problem is that the `on_guild_join` event only takes 1 argument, `guild`, which does not give you any information about the person who used the authorize link to add the bot to the guild.

Is there a way to do this? Do I have to use a "cheat" method like having a custom website that logs the account that uses the invite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since bots aren't "invited", there's instead an audit log event for when a bot is added. This lets you iterate through the logs matching specific criteria.

If your bot has access to the audit logs, you can search for a `bot_add` event:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    bot_entry = await guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.bot_add).flatten()
    await bot_entry[0].user.send("Hello! Thanks for inviting me!")
```

And if you wish to double-check the bot's ID against your own:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    def check(event):
        return event.target.id == client.user.id
    bot_entry = await guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.bot_add).find(check)
    await bot_entry.user.send("Hello! Thanks for inviting me!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.audit_logs()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.audit_logs)
- [`AuditLogAction.bot_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AuditLogAction.bot_add)
- [`AsyncIterator.find()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AsyncIterator.find)

Comment: It is possible, with enough ping, that another bot gets added before the event is gained, and then the bot could message the wrong member. Is there a check to see which bot was invited?

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63221321/discord-py-how-to-catch-the-user-who-invited-the-bot-solution)

With [discord.py 2.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can get the `BotIntegration` of a server and with that the user who invited the bot.

##### Example

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    # get all server integrations
    integrations = await guild.integrations()

    for integration in integrations:
        if isinstance(integration, discord.BotIntegration):
            if integration.application.user.name == bot.user.name:
                bot_inviter = integration.user# returns a discord.User object
                
                # send message to the inviter to say thank you
                await bot_inviter.send("Thank you for inviting my bot!!")
                break
```

**Note:** `guild.integrations()` requires the `Manage Server` ([`manage_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild%20integrations#discord.Permissions.manage_guild)) permission.

---

##### References:

- [`Guild.integrations`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild%20integrations#discord.Guild.integrations)
- [`discord.BotIntegration`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild#discord.BotIntegration)