# discord.py: How to get the user who invited/added the bot to his server? [solution]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to send a DM to the user, who invited/added the bot to his server. 
I noticed that it's displayed in the audit log. Can I fetch that and get the user or is there a easier way to achieve that?

###### Example:

```py
bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_guild(guild, inviter):
    await inviter.send("Thanks for adding the bot to your server!")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [discord.py 2.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can get the `BotIntegration` of a server and with that the user who invited the bot.

##### Example

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    # get all server integrations
    integrations = await guild.integrations()

    for integration in integrations:
        if isinstance(integration, discord.BotIntegration):
            if integration.application.user.name == bot.user.name:
                bot_inviter = integration.user # returns a discord.User object
                
                # send message to the inviter to say thank you
                await bot_inviter.send("Thank you for inviting my bot!!")
                break
```

**Note:** `guild.integrations()` requires the `Manage Server` ([`manage_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild%20integrations#discord.Permissions.manage_guild)) permission.

---

##### References:

- [`Guild.integrations`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild%20integrations#discord.Guild.integrations)
- [`discord.BotIntegration`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild#discord.BotIntegration)

Answer (score 1):

Discord.py doesn't support Bot Integrations yet. Please check this [Pull Request](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/pull/5874). Once it is merged, you can do `integration.user` to get the user who invited the bot.

Comment: `integration.user` does not guarantee that it is a bot's inviter because e.g. it could also be a `StreamIntegration`.

Answer (score 1):

In [discord.py 1.7.3](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/index.html) and lower does not have any actual method. However you can instead fetch the Audit Log Entry ([documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#audit-log-data)) and find out who invited the Bot from there.